# got an unexpected keyword argument 'with_labels'

Tags: python

I'm beginner in python and I'm trying to run a python program, so I have the following code :

```
import networkx as nx
import tsplib95
import tsplib95.distances as distances
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
SEED = 9876
# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
def draw_graph(graph, only_nodes=False):
    """
    Helper method for drawing TSP (tour) graphs.
    """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

    func = nx.draw_networkx

    if only_nodes:
        func = nx.draw_networkx_nodes

    func(data.node_coords, graph, node_size=25, with_labels=False, ax=ax)
if __name__ == '__main__':


    data = tsplib95.load('xqf131.tsp')

    # These we will use in our representation of a TSP problem: a list of
    # (city, coord)-tuples.
    cities = [(city, tuple(coord)) for city, coord in data.node_coords.items()]

    solution = tsplib95.load('xqf131.opt.tour')
    optimal = data.trace_tours(solution.tours)[0]

    print('Total optimal tour length is {0}.'.format(optimal))

    draw_graph(data.get_graph(), True)
```

When I execute my code I get the following error :

[image]

what is wrong with the draw_graph function?

If you have any idea help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where in the documentation do you see that parameter? https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html Did you copy from an older version of the code or some blog post?

Comment: I get it from this link https://github.com/N-Wouda/ALNS/blob/master/examples/travelling_salesman_problem.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `draw_networkx_nodes` doesn't have the keyword argument `with_labels` as the error message says. You can use a dict to store the keyword arguments and update it accordingly:

```py
def draw_graph(graph, only_nodes=False):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

    kwargs = dict(node_size=25, ax=ax)
    if only_nodes:
        func = nx.draw_networkx_nodes
    else:
        func = nx.draw_networkx
        kwargs.update(with_labels=False)

    func(data.node_coords, graph, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, that solves my problem, but normally I have to get a graph, I get nothing

Comment: Are you calling `draw_graph`? Or if you're using a notebook, are you running the cell that calls `draw_graph`?